# The dot "." isn't repeating last command

Tags: vim

Somehow the dot "." command isn't repeating the last command for me. I'm searching a file for the string "xml" by issuing `:/xml` and vi, as expected, takes me to the next find. But now when I press "." nothing happens (the cursor stays exactly there), although if I do `:/xml` again, I'm taken to the next find.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.` command only repeats the last change *(Normal Mode)*.

To repeat the last command-line, you can use `@:`

Comment: `n` also repeats the last search, and `N` (uppercase) repeats the last search in the *opposite* direction (up if you used `/` to search down, down if you used `?` to search up)

Answer (score 1):

in vi and vim, when I search for a string I put

```
/xml
```

then if the first occurrence is not what I want, I just hit slash then enter

```
/ < enter >
```

and it takes me to the next occurrence of xml

Comment: You can just press `n` to go to the next match.

Comment: Indeed you can. thanks! Many ways to skin that pesky cat